# MomentJS set timezone without changing time

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I'm trying to set the timezone for a date in moment.js without changing the time value

I get a date in utc:

```
date.toString() // Sun Sep 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000
```

and I need to set the time zone without changing the time.

```
Sun Sep 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500
```

if I use `date.utcOffset(moment().utcOffset())` it adds the offset:

```
date.toString() // Sat Sep 26 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500
```

I could do

```
date = moment(date.format("YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSSS"), "YYYYMMDDHHmmssSSSS")
```

but that seems like an inefficient way to do it.

Is there any method that will just change the timezone without changing the time?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the time of writing this (Moment 2.22), you could go from local to UTC with `someLocalMomentVariable.utc(true)` then back from UTC to local with `someUtcMomentVariable.local(true)`.

Comment: `date.local(true)` seems to work but I can't find any documentation on what parameters `.local()` accepts

Comment: looks like `.local(true)` was [added](https://github.com/moment/moment/blame/16dcad11fd28cad216d2c9f52f5a68dec7201139/moment.js#L2050) in v2.8.0

Comment: @TonyBrix yeah, not sure why its not documented.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using moment.js use `utcOffset` with true as second parameter.

```
date2 = moment(date1).utcOffset('+0400', true)
```

Or If you are using [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/), you can use `tz` function on moment object with second parameter as `true`.

```
date1 = moment(date1).tz('Asia/Kolkata', true)
```

Comment: This works great, but is there any documentation about the boolean parameter to the `tz` method on an existing `moment` instance?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/

Answer (score 8):

Using moment timezone, if you can identify the timezone you can also set it without adjusting time with by passing the `true` flag

```
const tz = "America/New_York"; // GMT-0500
moment(date).tz(tz, true); // true flag identifies not changing time when updating time zone
```

Documentation (though it does not explain the `boolean` flag)
[Converting to Zone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/)

Answer (score 3):

`moment().utcOffset(0).add(moment().utcOffset(), 'minutes').format()`

You'll have to do some sort of math, and without profiling there's no way to say which is the most efficient.

A javascript date object will always have the local timezone, so you'll need to work in moment objects or compensate.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set **different type of timezones** (**'Europe/Berlin'** and **'+05:00'**) with the moment-timezone, then you can do it with a **following steps:**

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';

// get timezone offset. From 'Europe/Berlin' to '+02:00'

function getOffsetValue(zoneName) {
  const offset = moment.tz(zoneName).format('Z');

  return offset;
}

 // check if it's '+02:00' format or text format 'Europe/Berlin'

const formatZone = zone => {
  if (zone[0] === '+' || zone[0] === '-') {
    return zone;
  }

  return getOffsetValue(zone);
};

export const addCustomTimezone = (zone) => { // pass your zones and periods here
  const shortDate = moment('2022.05.05 00:00:00 +01:00').format('2022.05.05 00:00:00'); // cutting off previous timezone

  return `${shortDate} ${formatZone(zone)}`;
};
```