# Set timezone/offset without changing actual time in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to convert from CST(-06:00) to IST(+05:30) using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). The problem is initially I am having only date and time. So when I am setting manually using `utcOffset(-360)` in moment, it actually changes the actual time. How can I set timezone/offset without changing the actual time. PFB the code snippet.

```js
var cstDate = "Jun 06, 2018 08:39 PM";
var convertedCSTDate = moment(cstDate, "MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm A").utcOffset(-360);
console.log(convertedCSTDate);
console.log(convertedCSTDate.format("HH:mm Z"));
var istDate = convertedCSTDate.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format("HH:mm Z");
console.log(istDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.min.js"></script><script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MomentJS set timezone without changing time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422282/momentjs-set-timezone-without-changing-time)

Comment: Can someone explain with some code?